# How to implement OpenAPI client side generator for React-Native app? [WITHOUT TYPESCRIPT]

Tags: javascript, react-native, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to implement OpenAPI Client side code generator in my react-native app where we are not using TypeScript. But all of the article which i have seen till now are are recommending to create react-native app with TypeScript template by using `typescript-axios` generator. Ref:
[How to automate API code generation (OpenAPI/Swagger) and boost productivity](https://medium.com/tribalscale/how-to-automate-api-code-generation-openapi-swagger-and-boost-productivity-1176a0056d8a)
I want to know how can we implement the same without typescript. I have seen that Javascript is also there in OpenAPI client side generators. But i don't know how to implement that